# Docker Port Mapping Doesn't render page in browser

Tags: python, node.js, docker, localhost

I'm trying to containerize a nodejs app into a container image.
So in the docker documents we see the correct way to map the host port to the container port is hostport:containerport
Using the same, I've tried to run the command:
docker run -i -t -p 3007:8080

Where 3007 is the port my nodejs app is listening to and 8080 is the hostport(my laptop).
But I keep getting the error "localhost refused to connect" when I hit localhost:8080 in my browser.
It wasn't until I swapped these port numbers like:
docker run -i -t -p 8080:3007 
To render the actual app (listening on port 3007) in my browser.
I'm confused as to why this happens? Am I missing any information?

Comment: The format is `-p hostPort:containerPort`. So, no surprise. I'm wondering what your interpretation of this terms is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.